# Turn string from JSON array into another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to port the following code to use JSON files http://malamas.com/jsuc/jsuc.html
Currently i have managed to take the 'unit' and 'factor' parts of this:

```
property[0] = "Acceleration";
unit[0] = new Array("Meter/sq.sec (m/sec^2)", "Foot/sq.sec (ft/sec^2)", "G (g)", "Galileo (gal)", "Inch/sq.sec (in/sec^2)");
factor[0] = new Array(1, .3048, 9.806650, .01, 2.54E-02);
```

and put them into a JSON line:

```
var text = '{"Accelleration": { "unit":"\\"Meter/sq.sec (m/sec^2)\\", \\"Foot/sq.sec (ft/sec^2)\\", \\"G (g)\\", \\"Galileo (gal)\\", \\"Inch/sq.sec (in/sec^2)\\"", "factor":"1, .3048, 9.806650, .01, 2.54E-02"}}'
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Which i can have output as a string like this

```
"Meter/sq.sec (m/sec^2)", "Foot/sq.sec (ft/sec^2)", "G (g)", "Galileo (gal)", "Inch/sq.sec (in/sec^2)"
```

but i want to be able to feed it into the top code by doing this:

```
property[0] = "Acceleration";
unit[0] = new Array(obj.Accelleration.unit);
factor[0] = new Array(obj.Accelleration.factor);
```

Unfortunately, when i do that, unit[0][0] brings up the same thing;

```
"Meter/sq.sec (m/sec^2)", "Foot/sq.sec (ft/sec^2)", "G (g)", "Galileo (gal)", "Inch/sq.sec (in/sec^2)"
```

How can i make it so it works as an array? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing it as a string first? If you're doing this in javascript you can just store the object directly without wrapping the object in a string.

Comment: As @Jhect said, use an OBJECT.

Comment: Can i have an example of how to do that in this situation? My understanding of JS and JSON files is extremely limited.

Comment: You're going to have some problems in your code if you keep spelling *acceleration* two different ways.

Comment: Yep, i sure am. Thanks for that :D

Comment: First you need to forget JSON completely. It's primarily meant for transferring data between two services (like the browser and the server) and if I understood correctly you're not doing that at all. Just read up on how to manage objects/arrays and skip everything that even mentions JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in your JSON is a string that contains some representation of strings. As that representation is not JSON, you can't parse it directly (but you could by adding brackets around it to turn it into JSON).

Instead of having a string that contains strings, make it an array that contains strings. Then when you parse it, you will already have the array:

```
var text = '{"Accelleration": { '+
  '"unit": ["Meter/sq.sec (m/sec^2)", "Foot/sq.sec (ft/sec^2)", "G (g)", "Galileo (gal)", "Inch/sq.sec (in/sec^2)" ], '+
  '"factor": [ 1, .3048, 9.806650, .01, 2.54E-02 ]'+
  '}}'
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Now you have your arrays, without having to do anything more than getting them from the object:

```
unit[0] = obj.Accelleration.unit;
factor[0] = obj.Accelleration.factor;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression i had to name all of the things in a JSON file for some odd reason.